# x86-64 System V abi - argument classification for parameter passing

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

The [x86_64 System V ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-draft.pdf) in Section 3.2.3 specifies which arguments of a function call go to which registers and which are pushed on the stack. I have troubles understanding the algorithm for the classification of aggregates, which says (the highlighting is mine):

> The classification of aggregate (structures and arrays) and union types works as follows:
>
> 1. If the size of an object is larger than eight eightbytes, or it contains unaligned fields, it has class MEMORY.
> 2. If a C++ object is non-trivial for the purpose of calls, as specified in the C++ ABI13, it is passed by invisible reference (the object is replaced in the parameter list by a pointer that has class INTEGER).
> 3. If the size of the aggregate exceeds a single eightbyte, **each is classified separately**. Each eightbyte gets initialized to class NO_CLASS.
> 4. **Each field of an object** is classified recursively so that always **two fields** are considered.  **The resulting class** is calculated according to the classes of the fields in the eightbyte: (a)  If both classes are equal, this is the resulting class. (b)  If one of the classes is NO_CLASS, the resulting class is the other class.(c)  If one of the classes is MEMORY, the result is the MEMORY class.(d)  If one of the classes is INTEGER, the result is the INTEGER. (e)  If  one  of  the  classes  is  X87,  X87UP,  COMPLEX_X87  class,  MEMORY  is used as class.(f)  Otherwise class SSE is used.
> 5. Then a post merger cleanup is done: (a)  If **one of the classes** is MEMORY, the whole argument is passed in memory. (b)  If X87UP is not preceded by X87, the whole argument is passed in memory. (c)  If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eightbyte isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument is passed in memory. (d)  If SSEUP is not preceded by SSE or SSEUP, it is converted to SSE

I do not understand points (3), (4), and (5). Specifically, I have the following questions:

Q1. In point (3), by "each is classified separately", do authors mean "each eightbyte"? If so, then I would expect that what follows is an explanation of classification of eightbytes.

Q2. In point (4), by "Each field of an object", do they mean "each field of an eightbyte that is a result of (separation in) point (3)?

Q3. In point (4), by "two fields" in "always two fields are considered", do they mean two successive fields?

Q4. In point (4), by "the resulting class", do they mean the class of the object, or of the eightbyte, or of the second considered field, or of something else? In the last case, where is the resulting class used? Does this mean that the algorithm keeps the field of the first field as is, and then iteratively computes the class of the next field, until we have the classes of all fields in the eightbyte? Or does it mean that we the algorithm processes two fields at once?

Q5. In point (4), what if there is only one field? Or an even number of fields?

Q6. In point (5), "one of the classes" of a field, or of an eightbyte?

If someone could provide something more formal/precise - e.g., a pseudo-code or a flow-chart - that would be ideal.

Comment: Point (4) mentions "the fields in the eightbyte". According to point (1), the classification of individual fields applies only to aggregates with aligned fields. The normal alignment is 4 bytes, so one eightbyte can contain at most 2 fields. I'm not sure that the "**always** two fields" in point (4) is correct. Maybe this helps to understand the specification.

Comment: @Bodo But what if we have a structure `struct S {char x; char y; char z;}`? Since the alignment of chars is 1 byte, we have 3 fields in an eightbyte.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think of this case.

Comment: Point (1) is wrong. It should be "two eightbytess" instead of "eight eitghbytes"

Comment: @EvanL00: How do you figure it is “wrong”? The quoted text is as it appears in the linked document; the original document says “1. If the size of an object is larger than eight eightbytes…” That is a draft version, but it is in [the release version](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) too. If you are suggesting it is an error in the original because point 4 discusses two fields, suggesting just two eightbytes in the aggregate, point 5 shows that cases with more than two eightbytes are involved: “If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil
This link https://c9x.me/compile/doc/abi.html 's point 4 mentioned "two eightbytes". And I have tested with some code in godbolt.org (I'll attach it when I find it)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Here is the updated comment.
This link https://c9x.me/compile/doc/abi.html 's point 4 mentioned "two eightbytes". And the following `s` is passed in the stack, so it is MEMORY, right?
```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
class s {
    public:
    int i;
    int d;
    int j;
    int k;
    int g;
    int h;
};
void g(s pi, int j) {

}
int main() {

    s s1;
    int i = 4;
    g(s1, i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See [the `gcc` implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/i386.c#L2080).

Clarification for Point 1 (in response to the comment saying "eight is a typo and should be two instead"):

> 1. If the size of an object is larger than eight eightbytes, or it contains unaligned fields, it has class MEMORY.

```
      /* On x86-64 we pass structures larger than 64 bytes on the stack.  */
      if (bytes > 64)
        return 0;
```

The function returns the number of registers to use for parameters, and zero means memory should be used instead.

(Later, after the analysis, if there are more than two eightbytes, registers are used only if the first is SSE and the rest are SSEUP, as pointed out in 5.(c):

> (c) If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eightbyte isn't SSE or any other eightbyte isn't SSEUP, the whole argument is passed in memory.)

---

> Q1. In point (3), by "each is classified separately", do authors mean "each eightbyte"?

Yes. In the code, each **eightbyte** is called a `word`.

> Each eightbyte gets initialized to class NO_CLASS.

```
  int words = CEIL (bytes + (bit_offset % 64) / 8, UNITS_PER_WORD);
  // ...
      for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
        classes[i] = X86_64_NO_CLASS;
```

---

> Q2. In point (4), by "Each field of an object", do they mean "each field of an eightbyte that is a result of (separation in) point (3)?

No, they mean each field of a struct/class, or union, or array elements. These are handled in a couple of places in the code, but you will see `for` loops like:

```
          for (field = TYPE_FIELDS (type); field; field = DECL_CHAIN (field))
```

This is why it is recursive. The fields themselves can be aggregate types. The entire logic is applied starting with each field, and the recursive function:

- either returns 0, meaning the whole thing is passed in memory,
- or it returns the number of registers (eightbytes) that would be used and the classes of each one (recursion through the nested fields will terminate at fields with non-aggregate types).

```
                      num = classify_argument (TYPE_MODE (type), type,
                                               subclasses,
                                               (int_bit_position (field)
                                               + bit_offset) % 512);
                      if (!num)
                        return 0;
```

---

> Q3. In point (4), by "two fields" in "always two fields are considered", do they mean two successive fields?

I don't think "fields" is accurate here. And not successive. What it is doing is merging the classes determined so far for each `word`, with the classes recursively determined for the fields that correspond to the same `word`s. See below:

```
                      pos = (int_bit_position (field)
                            + (bit_offset % 64)) / 8 / 8;
                      for (i = 0; i < num && (i + pos) < words; i++)
                        classes[i + pos]
                          = merge_classes (subclasses[i], classes[i + pos]);
```

Starting from `pos` (the eightbyte that this field is in) each class gets merged with the subclass determined by the recursive call for the field.

---

> Q4. In point (4), by "the resulting class", do they mean the class of the object, or of the eightbyte, or of the second considered field, or of something else?

This is now describing the `merge_classes` function, which takes the two classes and returns the merged class for the eightbyte. We are iterating over fields but classes are for eightbytes.

> In the last case, where is the resulting class used?

Each class will determine the type of the corresponding register (GPR/SSE/X87 etc.).

---

> Q5. In point (4), what if there is only one field? Or an even number of fields?

I hope "two field" is answered at this point. If, say, a struct has one field, the class will be initialized for that eightbyte as `NO_CLASS`, then for the field it will be determined as, say, `INTEGER`. Then at merge, the class will become `INTEGER`.

---

> Q6. In point (5), "one of the classes" of a field, or of an eightbyte?

Of an eightbyte. Classes are always referring to an eightbyte.